# How to get a list of all html elements in PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom

According to the documentation for [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), I can call the function with `"*"` argument, and get a list of all HTML elements from some HTML code.

However, with the following code:

```
<?php
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML("<html><body><div>hello</div><div>bye</div></body></html>");
  $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("*");

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $new_text= new DOMText($node->textContent."MODIFIED");

    $node->removeChild($node->firstChild);
    $node->appendChild($new_text);
  }
  $content = $dom->saveHTML();
  echo $content;
?>
```

I get a list of only one element, and the result of execution of the code above is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>hellobyeMODIFIED</html>
```

while I would expect something like this:

```
<html><body><div>helloMODIFIED</div><div>byeMODIFIED</div></body></html>
```

Shouldn't `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` method return a list of as many HTML elements as available in the HTML code?

Note:  I need  to create DOMText instances explicitly, because I need this to work in PHP 5.4. `DOMNode::textContent` is accessible for writing only from PHP 5.6

Comment: Your elements have the same tag name...

Comment: @Alexis, yes, but if I change the getElementsByTagName("*") by getElementsByTagName("div"), then I get the result that I want, and the elements still have the same tag name.

Comment: @MarcosFernandez, it is unclear what exactly do you want to achieve. Do you want to modify all text nodes? Or do you want to modify all text nodes of the leaves (the last tags) having text nodes? For example, how this sequence is supposed to be modified `<div>text<span>abc</span>def</div>`?

Comment: @Ruslan Osmanov I need to process all text elements present in the page. They won't necessarily be modified, but I have to check them. In your example, in the case that all those text elements should be modified, the outcome woud be: `<div>textMODIFIED<span>abcMODIFIED</span>defMODIFIED</div>`

Comment: You mention that you need it to work in PHP 5.4 even though you're aware of features in 5.6 that could help. Just how difficult would it be to upgrade? There are virtually no significant backward compatibility issues between 5.4 and 5.6, so an upgrade should be pretty easy. Also, 5.4 is no longer supported, so really you should be considering upgrading anyway.

Comment: @Simba, upgrading is not difficult, but it is just not in my hands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` method actually returns all the tags, if the first argument is `'*'`. But your code replaces `<body>` tag (including all child nodes) with a text node at the first iteration.

Iterate the nodes, and modify only the nodes with `nodeType` property equal to `XML_TEXT_NODE`:

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  for ($child = $node->firstChild; $child; $child = $child->nextSibling) {
    if (! ($child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE && trim($child->textContent))) {
      continue;
    }

    // The textContent is writable since PHP 5.6.1
    if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50601) {
      $child->textContent .= 'MODIFIED';
      continue;
    }

    // For older versions, create DOMText explicitly
    $text = new DOMText($child->textContent . 'MODIFIED');
    try {
      if ($child->parentNode->replaceChild($text, $child))
        $child = $text;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      trigger_error("Failed to modify text '$child->textContent': "
        . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_WARNING);
    }
  }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Note, for PHP versions 5.6.1 and newer, you don't need to create `DOMText` instances explicitly, since the `DOMNode::textContent` property is accessible for read and write. So you can simply modify the text by assigning a string value to this property. Only make sure that the node has no child nodes other than `XML_TEXT_NODE`.

The code above checks if `trim($child->textContent)` is not empty, because the document may contain extra space characters (including newline), e.g.:

```
<div><!-- newline/spaces -->
  <span>text</span><!-- newline/spaces -->
</div><!-- newline/spaces -->
```

Comment: Thanks, that's (almost) it! Just one thing: I do need  to create DOMText instances explicitly, because I need this to work in PHP 5.4. `DOMNode::textContent` is accessible for writing only from PHP 5.6 on. I am still not being able to make this work on 5.4.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I was stuck with the child->parentNode thing. And thanks for the nice explanations, too. Lot of time saved!

Answer (score 1):

This function 'DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName' returns a new instance of class DOMNodeList containing all the elements.

And it works fine:

```php
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML("<html><body><div>hello</div><div>bye</div></body></html>");
  $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("*");

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->tagName."<br />";
  }
?>
```

it output all tags of your document.

Probably you need smth like:

```
<?php


    $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->loadHTML("<html><body><div>hello</div><div>bye</div></body></html>");
      $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("*");

      foreach ($nodes as $node) {
          if ($node->tagName=='div'){
            $node->nodeValue .= "new content";
          }
      }

      $content = $dom->saveHTML();
      echo htmlspecialchars($content);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element ){

}
```